# Reporting content reproduced without attribution

Tags: discussion, attribution

What are the recommended steps if I notice content taken from SO/SF/SU which is placed on another site without respecting the terms of use?

Specifically I've commented on [this blog](http://maneeshchaturvedi.blogspot.com/2009/07/eclipse-templates-for-auto-code.html) having recognized the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates/1029304#1029304) but I got no answer - comment was not even published.

What would be the next step?

Comment: I noticed this again today; https://copycoding.com/d/google-bigquery-partitioning-a-table-best-practices copies data from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743050/whats-a-good-balance-to-decide-when-to-partition-a-table-in-bigquery without attribution, and sadly appears above the original post in Google searches (such as https://www.google.com/search?q=big+query+ideal+partition+size+best+practices).

Answer (score 2):

Surely, the greater crime is putting 'Working with an IDE tends to make life *quiet* simple' when he meant 'Working with an IDE tends to make life **quite** simple'. :-)

Seriously though - interesting question. I guess all people can really do is to apply peer pressure and publicly ask for attribution? If he blocks your comments, I'm not sure there's much more you CAN do.

(Though it would be nice to be wrong on that!)

Comment: Jeff has discussed sending DCMA notices to sites that infringe heavily. I don't think it would be worth it over one blog post though.